# Is this the most efficient way for a custom filter?

Tags: java, replace, filter

Im asking me if my code is a common and most efficient way for a custom filter. The user can choose which characters can be used/notUsed. The dirty text can be very long so i have to see that my code needs to be efficient as possible:

```
    String dirtyText = "iamacleantext<>>";
    String allowedCharacters = "abcdefhijk$<>/lmnoqrgstuvwxyz";

    String result = dirtyText.replaceAll("[" + allowedCharacters + "]","");

    if (result.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Ok, your text can be used");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry the text contains not allowed characters");
    }
```

would be thankful for someone who has more knowledge about this

Comment: did you run the code? i just need to check whether the code is clean or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have [been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023792/regex-vs-contains-best-performance) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28208793/in-java-which-is-faster-string-containssome-text-or-regex-that-looks-for) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848309/string-contains-vs-setstring-contains-vs-regex-string-matches) regards [`String.contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) vs. regex. According to most of the threads it's clear that regex performance are poorer. An alternative approach (which bails out on the first illegal character):

```
private static boolean check(String dirtyText) {
    String allowedCharacters = "abcdefhijk$<>/lmnoqrgstuvwxyz";
    for (int i=0; i < dirtyText.length(); i++) {
        if (!allowedCharacters.contains(dirtyText.substring(i, i+1))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is better than OP's solution because it will fail as soon as an invalid character is found. If you have a string of one million invalid characters, that becomes significant.

Comment: in fact! regex took 1350016 ns and contains just
took 189994 ns. Thank you very much

Comment: @Michael That's only because OP is replacing the entire string first. `String.matches()` would probably perform much better.